# How to redirect search for node_modules in other directory

Tags: node.js, npm

Hi I want to aceess npm modules from directory that is not the current one. The global modules are not solution since the dependency they involve. I want to have a container with all the modules I have downloaded and to redirect `require` to that directory instead of the current directory. That way all my projects could search for modules in a relative path like this `../` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

For example,

Let's say you have 10 local node package repositories (with `package.json` inside each package) in `/User/you/modules` and your project is in `/User/you/project`.

All you need to do is, link all modules in `/User/you/modules` directory to `/User/you/project`.

```
cd /User/you/project
find /User/you/modules/* -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec npm link {} \;
```

Now, you can use all your modules from `/User/you/modules` in `/User/you/project` without relative path.

So, you can now;

```
require('package-name')
```

> `package-name` is taken from `package.json`, not from directory name.

instead of;

```
require('../modules/package-name')
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`NODE_PATH`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) environment variable before/when running your app and this will allow you to add your own directories to the paths Node tries to resolve packages from.

---

The below example seems to work well when run as such: `NODE_PATH=./lib node app.js`

**app.js**

`require('api')();`

**lib/api.js**

`module.exports = () => console.log('hello');`

---

[Here is an interesting Gist](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) which includes some other routes if the above doesn't look appropriate for you. There is also some interesting discussion in the comments between some of the prominent Node.js folks.